# Drop multiple columns in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 1000 columns in my dataframe, and I want to drop 3rd, 5th, 7th, 9th....999th columns, but need to keep the 1st column. I am not sure if df.drop function can deal with this issue. any ideas? The following code drops all odd columns include 1st column. but I need to keep the 1st column

```
col_to_drop = df.columns[np.array([i for i in range(df.shape[1]) if i%2!= 1 and i != 1])]

df.drop(col_to_drop, axis=1)
```

Comment: Nope no issues.  Should work as planned.

Comment: Can you help to show how to make that work?

Comment: @WeiZhang, are you reading data from Excel or CSV? if so then you can only choose the desired cols rest you can drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(10,-1), columns=[*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])
df.drop(df.columns[np.r_[2,4,5,6,9]], axis=1)
# or df.drop(df.columns[np.array([2,4,5,6,9])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A   B   D   H   I
0   0   1   3   7   8
1  10  11  13  17  18
2  20  21  23  27  28
3  30  31  33  37  38
4  40  41  43  47  48
5  50  51  53  57  58
6  60  61  63  67  68
7  70  71  73  77  78
8  80  81  83  87  88
9  90  91  93  97  98
```

## Update for 1,000 columns.

#### Drops every odd colum except 1. -> 3,5,7,9...999

```
col_to_drop = df.columns[np.array([i for i in range(df.shape[1]) if i%2 != 0 and i != 0])]

df.drop(col_to_drop, axis=1)
```

Comment: 10 columns are easy to manage, but if I have 1000 column and need to drop 498 columns, it will be tedious

Comment: looks like this code drops even number, not odd columns

Comment: actually No, please help again

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like below:

```
>>> df
    A   B   C   D   E
0  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1
1  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2
2  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3
3  A4  B4  C4  D4  E4
4  A5  B5  C5  D5  E5
```

### Drop unwanted columns:

```
>>> df.drop(ex.columns[[0, 4, 2]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

### Result:

```
>>> df
    B   D
0  B1  D1
1  B2  D2
2  B3  D3
3  B4  D4
4  B5  D5
```

Another way around:

```
>>> df
     A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P
0   24  27  61  40  12  20  52  95  47  23  92  97  86  73  89  84
1   88  33  39  38  87   7  38  31  77   0  66  41  30  34  80   4
2    8  45  68  99  21  66   6  54  28  48  29  18  12  56  30   3
3   22  79  37   1  32   5  53  13   0  57  54  97  71  86  84  12
4   94  19   8  99  91  91  77  90  56  50  41   4  70  36  56  58
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
95  70  22  73  15  41  50  81  38  31  78  94  72  62  56  78  17
96  13  45  40  83  25  24  73  30  67  85  98  63  32   1  70  97
97  24  58  74  64   0  43  36  27  17  76  51  36  85  39  15  77
98  29   3  73  57  39  70  45  53  83  98  92  51  49  45  85  71
99  74  22  77  87   4  16  69  77  39  88  71  73  39   8  63  34

[100 rows x 16 columns]
```

As you want to drop all the odd columns hence other way around is to opt all the even column then while using `.loc` indexer as follows.

```
>>> df.loc[:, ::2]
     A   C   E   G   I   K   M   O
0   24  61  12  52  47  92  86  89
1   88  39  87  38  77  66  30  80
2    8  68  21   6  28  29  12  30
3   22  37  32  53   0  54  71  84
4   94   8  91  77  56  41  70  56
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
95  70  73  41  81  31  94  62  78
96  13  40  25  73  67  98  32  70
97  24  74   0  36  17  51  85  15
98  29  73  39  45  83  92  49  85
99  74  77   4  69  39  71  39  63

[100 rows x 8 columns]
```

OR

```
>>> df[df.columns[::2]]
     A   C   E   G   I   K   M   O
0   24  61  12  52  47  92  86  89
1   88  39  87  38  77  66  30  80
2    8  68  21   6  28  29  12  30
3   22  37  32  53   0  54  71  84
4   94   8  91  77  56  41  70  56
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
95  70  73  41  81  31  94  62  78
96  13  40  25  73  67  98  32  70
97  24  74   0  36  17  51  85  15
98  29  73  39  45  83  92  49  85
99  74  77   4  69  39  71  39  63

[100 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: I want to drop all odd columns except 1st column

Answer (score 0):

A little change from scott Boston's answer works perfectly for this case

```
col_to_drop = df.columns[np.array([i for i in range(df.shape[1]) if i%2 != 1 and i != 0])]

df.drop(col_to_drop, axis=1)
```

Comment: Okay modified my solution to match.  Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) my solution?